# Insert a drop down inside Nolan

Tags: matrix, drop-down, nolan

Nolan is working fine, but it is possible  to insert a drop down inside a cell, as the Field Pack dropdown inside a Matrix cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO this is not possible according to the [documentation](http://iain.co.nz/software/docs/nolan). If this is really important I would suggest contacting the developer to see if that could be added in. If it's possible you'd likely have to pay for the time to add the new functionality.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Sean. I've turned this question in a bounty to have more information, because I've contacted the author, and i didn't have return. It's not so important, just it would be genial if this option will exist :)